# Upload .ipynb to wix blog

Tags: file-upload, jupyter-notebook, blogs

I am writing a blog on wix and was wondering if there is any way to upload .ipynb to the blog space. Has anyone done this before? I am using Jupyter notebooks and would ideally like to upload the notebook to wix so that it is formatted in the same way the notebook is, or like a markdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can export a Jupyter Notebook as an html file.  Just know that it's a static document and it will not be interactive.